# JavaScript button function swap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert

What I am trying to do is following:
I have an input type button and I want to replace it's function on first click.

```
<input type="submit" class="submit-button" value="Submit" name="boom" />
```

So a [button] that serves for submit, I wanna show alert with some jquery plugins but lets do it here with normal javascript alert (default window).

So on first click it will be

```
alert('Something');
```

And on second click it will be default function (submit).

How can I achieve something like this?

Of course if button is clicked once, and then page reloaded, it will show same alert again on first button click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element.

Example:

```
$(".submit-button").one("click", function(e) {
    // will only run on first click of element
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Something"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clicked = false;

    function btnClick(e) {
        if(clicked === false) {
            alert('Something');
            clicked = true;
            e.preventDefault();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<input type="submit" onclick="btnClick(event)" class="submit-button" value="Submit" name="boom" />
```

Comment: Not as elegant as Rory's solution, but it looked like you wanted to stick to raw javascript, so I avoided jQuery in my answer. Glad you got it figured out! :)